# DirectX alpha blending not working in UWP

Tags: c++, uwp, directx

I have an application based on the Windows8-DirectX template from the Visual Studio and i'm trying to draw a texture with an alpha channel with the following `D3D11_BLEND_DESC`:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc{};
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;

blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_DEST_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;

blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &_blendState));
```

And i'm binding this blend state this way:

```
float blendFactor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
UINT sampleMask = 0xffffffff;
context->OMSetBlendState(_blendState.Get(), blendFactor, sampleMask);
```

Here is my Vertex Shader:

```
cbuffer ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix model;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float3 pos : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
};

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
};

PixelShaderInput main(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    PixelShaderInput output;
    float4 pos = float4(input.pos, 1.0f);

    pos = mul(pos, model);
    pos = mul(pos, view);
    pos = mul(pos, projection);
    output.pos = pos;

    output.texcoord = input.texcoord;

    return output;
}
```

Pixel Shader:

```
Texture2D tex0;
SamplerState s0;

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
};

float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 color = tex0.Sample(s0, input.texcoord);
    return  color;
}
```

And that is my texture:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc{};
textureDesc.Width = width;
textureDesc.Height = height;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.MipLevels = textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &_texture));
ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateShaderResourceView(_texture.Get(), NULL, &_textureView));
```

But the problem is that the blending is not working properly. An texture is only blending with the background, but not with another texture, eg. if i call the `ClearRenderTargetView` method with blue color as third parameter then the partially transparent texture will be bluish but will not be blended with an overlapping texture.

Comment: Blending depends on the order in which you render. Transparent objects have to be rendered last.

Comment: I have two planes: one with transparent texture and one with non-transparent texture and i'm drawing them in the following order: first i'm setting blend state, then i'm drawing the transparent plane and at the end i'm drawing the non-transparent plane.

Comment: If i reverse the order (first non-transparent then transparent), then the transparent plane will be not visible.

Comment: Then you also have a depth problem. Try to turn off the depth test.